# How to check whether a base class object or derived object?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a `BankAccount` class. `FixedBankAccount` and `SavingsBankAccount` are derived from it.
I need to throw an exception if the recieved object is not a derived object. I have the following code.

```
IEnumerable<DBML_Project.BankAccount> accounts = AccountRepository.GetAllAccountsForUser(userId);
foreach (DBML_Project.BankAccount acc in accounts)
{
    string typeResult = Convert.ToString(acc.GetType());
    string baseValue = Convert.ToString(typeof(DBML_Project.BankAccount));

    if (String.Equals(typeResult, baseValue))
    {
        throw new Exception("Not correct derived type");
    }
}

namespace DBML_Project
{

public  partial class BankAccount
{
    // Define the domain behaviors
    public virtual void Freeze()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

public class FixedBankAccount : BankAccount
{
    public override void Freeze()
    {
        this.Status = "FrozenFA";
    }
}

public class SavingsBankAccount : BankAccount
{
    public override void Freeze()
    {
        this.Status = "FrozenSB";
    }
}

} // namespace DBML_Project
```

Is there any better code than this?

Comment: Its ok, just change to if(acc.getType() == typeof(DBML_Project.BankAccount))

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. The compiler won't let you, or anyone else, add an obejct to `accounts` that is not derived from `BankAccount`, so you do not need to check that.

Comment: @AseemGautam: That will return `false` if `acc` is of a derived type.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: It will? Sorry, did not know that!

Comment: The answer of @bhuvin is correct from the design point of view, you should not have to check for the types at first place.

Comment: I cannot make base class abstract. Some other clients need to instantiate the base class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define an interface (something like IAccettableBankAccount, but you know your domain, so you should be able to find a better name) and have FixedBankAccount and SavingsBankAccount implement it. Then your test would simply be:

```
if (!acc is IAccettableBankAccount)
{
     throw new Exception("Not correct derived type");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Is it better than my current implementation?

Comment: It depends. For sure it gives you more control, i.e. in your implementation every subclass of BankAccount (even future classes) will always be OK, with the interface you could have classes which are derived from BankAccount, but can throw your exception.

Answer (score 12):

You should be using [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)

```
if (acc.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BankAccount)))
    // base class
else
    // derived
```

Answer (score 5):

Declare BankAccount class as Abstract.

Comment: How does this help with the question?

Comment: It will constrain the caller of the method to only pass the derived types and there will not need for the check at all.

Comment: Ooh, now I get what he's actually asking for ... from reading the question, it seemed like he wanted to check the type compatibility on his own.

Comment: I cannot make base class abstract. Some other clients need to instantiate the base class

Comment: From design point of view there should be no need to create BankAccount instance,

Comment: @Lijo - Dude the design in that case needs a scan. Coz designwise that shoudn't be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Type.IsSubclassOf` Method. For more info check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx)

```
foreach (DBML_Project.BankAccount acc in accounts)
{
    if (!acc.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(DBML_Project.BankAccount))
    {
        throw new Exception("Not correct derived type");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the types directly:

```
    var accounts = AccountRepository.GetAllAccountsForUser(userId);
    if (accounts.Any(acc => acc.GetType() == typeof(DBML_Project.BankAccount))) {
        throw new Exception("Not correct derived type");
    }
```

Declaring the class as abstract might help, too, but i don't know if that's an option in your case.